# Tensorflow Object Detection Api Tests Fail

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-model-garden

Hi Tensorflow users and community,

I was running the [Tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tensorflow-installation) for object detection and I got some issues, I don't know if the installation was the problem, but all the commands exited successfully, and I got stuck with this.

- Protobuf Version: *3.12.4*
- Python Version: *Python 3.8.5*
- tensorboard                   *2.3.0*
- tensorboard-plugin-wit        *1.7.0*
- tensorflow                    *2.3.0*
- tensorflow-addons             *0.11.0*
- tensorflow-datasets           *3.2.1*
- tensorflow-estimator          *2.3.0*
- tensorflow-hub                *0.8.0*
- tensorflow-metadata           *0.22.2*
- tensorflow-model-optimization *0.4.1*
- Object Detection: *0.1*

Note that the object detection was installed from the git from models as it stands out in the docs:

```
# From within TensorFlow/models/research/
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install .
```

The command in question is the last for testing the installation of object detection:

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
```

And I got several assertion errors, some of the examples:

```
[  FAILED  ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_center_net_model
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_experimental_model
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_experimental_model): 0.0s
I0806 12:27:07.016419  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_experimental_model): 0.0s
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_experimental_model
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_from_config_with_crop_feature(True)
```

The full trace for the first assertion:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_create_center_net_model (__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test)
test_create_center_net_model (__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test)
Test building a CenterNet model from proto txt.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 224, in test_create_center_net_model
    model = model_builder.build(config, is_training=True)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 1015, in build
    return build_func(getattr(model_config, meta_architecture), is_training,
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 915, in _build_center_net_model
    feature_extractor = _build_center_net_feature_extractor(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 977, in _build_center_net_feature_extractor
    return CENTER_NET_EXTRACTOR_FUNCTION_MAP[feature_extractor_config.type](
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\object_detection\models\center_net_resnet_feature_extractor.py", line 141, in resnet_v2_101
    return CenterNetResnetFeatureExtractor(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\object_detection\models\center_net_resnet_feature_extractor.py", line 45, in __init__
    super(CenterNetResnetFeatureExtractor, self).__init__(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\object_detection\meta_architectures\center_net_meta_arch.py", line 71, in __init__
    super(CenterNetFeatureExtractor, self).__init__(name=name)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 308, in __init__
    self._init_batch_counters()
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 317, in _init_batch_counters
    self._train_counter = variables.Variable(0, dtype='int64', aggregation=agg)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 262, in __call__
    return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 244, in _variable_v2_call
    return previous_getter(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 237, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kws: default_variable_creator_v2(None, **kws)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 2633, in default_variable_creator_v2
    return resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 264, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 1507, in __init__
    self._init_from_args(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 1661, in _init_from_args
    handle = eager_safe_variable_handle(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 242, in eager_safe_variable_handle
    return _variable_handle_from_shape_and_dtype(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 174, in _variable_handle_from_shape_and_dtype
    gen_logging_ops._assert(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_logging_ops.py", line 49, in _assert
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 6843, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [0] [Op:Assert] name: EagerVariableNameReuse
```

Full Log Output:

```
e:\Desenvolvimento\tensorflow\models\research>python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
2020-08-06 12:27:02.162481: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
Running tests under Python 3.8.5: C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_center_net_model
2020-08-06 12:27:06.544000: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.578948: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 750 Ti computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 1.0845GHz coreCount: 5 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 80.47GiB/s
2020-08-06 12:27:06.580046: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.585764: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.591360: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.593618: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.602037: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.605579: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.621708: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.622257: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-06 12:27:06.636567: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x22c29ba5390 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-06 12:27:06.637042: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-08-06 12:27:06.637604: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 750 Ti computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 1.0845GHz coreCount: 5 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 80.47GiB/s
2020-08-06 12:27:06.638471: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.638806: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.639066: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.639327: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.639595: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.639862: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.640216: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-06 12:27:06.640572: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-06 12:27:06.720806: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-08-06 12:27:06.721274: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-08-06 12:27:06.721713: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N
2020-08-06 12:27:06.722232: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1455 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 750 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
2020-08-06 12:27:06.726211: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x22c2a0972c0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-06 12:27:06.726554: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 750 Ti, Compute Capability 5.0
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_center_net_model): 1.4s
I0806 12:27:07.006418  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_center_net_model): 1.4s
[  FAILED  ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_center_net_model
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_experimental_model
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_experimental_model): 0.0s
I0806 12:27:07.016419  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_experimental_model): 0.0s
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_experimental_model
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_from_config_with_crop_feature(True)
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_from_config_with_crop_feature(True)): 0.02s
I0806 12:27:07.038428  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_from_config_with_crop_feature(True)): 0.02s
[  FAILED  ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_from_config_with_crop_feature(True)
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_from_config_with_crop_feature(False)
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_from_config_with_crop_feature(False)): 0.01s
I0806 12:27:07.058416  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_from_config_with_crop_feature(False)): 0.01s
[  FAILED  ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_from_config_with_crop_feature(False)
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_model_from_config_with_example_miner
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_model_from_config_with_example_miner): 0.01s
I0806 12:27:07.075416  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_model_from_config_with_example_miner): 0.01s
[  FAILED  ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_model_from_config_with_example_miner
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_faster_rcnn_with_matmul
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_faster_rcnn_with_matmul): 0.01s
I0806 12:27:07.092416  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_faster_rcnn_with_matmul): 0.01s
[  FAILED  ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_faster_rcnn_with_matmul
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_faster_rcnn_without_matmul
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_faster_rcnn_without_matmul): 0.01s
I0806 12:27:07.111420  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_faster_rcnn_without_matmul): 0.01s
[  FAILED  ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_faster_rcnn_without_matmul
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_mask_rcnn_with_matmul
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_mask_rcnn_with_matmul): 0.02s
I0806 12:27:07.131419  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_mask_rcnn_with_matmul): 0.02s
[  FAILED  ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_mask_rcnn_with_matmul
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_mask_rcnn_without_matmul
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_mask_rcnn_without_matmul): 0.02s
I0806 12:27:07.151418  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_mask_rcnn_without_matmul): 0.02s
[  FAILED  ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_mask_rcnn_without_matmul
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_rfcn_model_from_config
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_rfcn_model_from_config): 0.02s
I0806 12:27:07.171454  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_rfcn_model_from_config): 0.02s
[  FAILED  ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_rfcn_model_from_config
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_ssd_fpn_model_from_config
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_ssd_fpn_model_from_config): 0.01s
I0806 12:27:07.182456  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_ssd_fpn_model_from_config): 0.01s
[  FAILED  ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_ssd_fpn_model_from_config
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_ssd_models_from_config
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_ssd_models_from_config): 0.01s
I0806 12:27:07.193453  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_ssd_models_from_config): 0.01s
[  FAILED  ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_create_ssd_models_from_config
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_faster_rcnn_batchnorm_update
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_faster_rcnn_batchnorm_update): 0.0s
I0806 12:27:07.198454  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_faster_rcnn_batchnorm_update): 0.0s
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_faster_rcnn_batchnorm_update
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_first_stage_nms_iou_threshold
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_first_stage_nms_iou_threshold): 0.0s
I0806 12:27:07.203454  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_first_stage_nms_iou_threshold): 0.0s
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_first_stage_nms_iou_threshold
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_model_config_proto
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_model_config_proto): 0.0s
I0806 12:27:07.205455  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_model_config_proto): 0.0s
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_model_config_proto
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_second_stage_batch_size
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_second_stage_batch_size): 0.0s
I0806 12:27:07.208452  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_second_stage_batch_size): 0.0s
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_invalid_second_stage_batch_size
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_session
[  SKIPPED ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_session
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_unknown_faster_rcnn_feature_extractor
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_unknown_faster_rcnn_feature_extractor): 0.0s
I0806 12:27:07.212455  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_unknown_faster_rcnn_feature_extractor): 0.0s
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_unknown_faster_rcnn_feature_extractor
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_unknown_meta_architecture
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_unknown_meta_architecture): 0.0s
I0806 12:27:07.213455  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_unknown_meta_architecture): 0.0s
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_unknown_meta_architecture
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_unknown_ssd_feature_extractor
INFO:tensorflow:time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_unknown_ssd_feature_extractor): 0.0s
I0806 12:27:07.217455  4260 test_util.py:1972] time(__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_unknown_ssd_feature_extractor): 0.0s
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTF2Test.test_unknown_ssd_feature_extractor
======================================================================
ERROR: test_create_center_net_model (__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test)
test_create_center_net_model (__main__.ModelBuilderTF2Test)
Test building a CenterNet model from proto txt.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 224, in test_create_center_net_model
    model = model_builder.build(config, is_training=True)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 1015, in build
    return build_func(getattr(model_config, meta_architecture), is_training,
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 915, in _build_center_net_model
    feature_extractor = _build_center_net_feature_extractor(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 977, in _build_center_net_feature_extractor
    return CENTER_NET_EXTRACTOR_FUNCTION_MAP[feature_extractor_config.type](
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\object_detection\models\center_net_resnet_feature_extractor.py", line 141, in resnet_v2_101
    return CenterNetResnetFeatureExtractor(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\object_detection\models\center_net_resnet_feature_extractor.py", line 45, in __init__
    super(CenterNetResnetFeatureExtractor, self).__init__(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\object_detection\meta_architectures\center_net_meta_arch.py", line 71, in __init__
    super(CenterNetFeatureExtractor, self).__init__(name=name)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 308, in __init__
    self._init_batch_counters()
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 317, in _init_batch_counters
    self._train_counter = variables.Variable(0, dtype='int64', aggregation=agg)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 262, in __call__
    return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 244, in _variable_v2_call
    return previous_getter(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 237, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kws: default_variable_creator_v2(None, **kws)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 2633, in default_variable_creator_v2
    return resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 264, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 1507, in __init__
    self._init_from_args(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 1661, in _init_from_args
    handle = eager_safe_variable_handle(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 242, in eager_safe_variable_handle
    return _variable_handle_from_shape_and_dtype(
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 174, in _variable_handle_from_shape_and_dtype
    gen_logging_ops._assert(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_logging_ops.py", line 49, in _assert
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
File "C:\Users\IuriAndreazza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 6843, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [0] [Op:Assert] name: EagerVariableNameReuse

*REMOVED TO REDUCE SIZE OF THE MESSAGE*

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 20 tests in 1.615s

FAILED (errors=11, skipped=1)
```

Anyone that that face some similar issue?

Thanks!

Comment: To anyone that could drop in this question, there are issues on TensorFlow

Here:  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41855
Here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42055
and Here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38518

Answer (score 0):

I used followed the same tutorial in colab and didn't face any issues. Here's my [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dQDCmRG28QBHDWoD3OsvUBzjSbhAuPnz?usp=sharing).

Installing the dependencies and protos might be what you need.

Try these:

```
cd models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cd models/research
pip install .
```

Other resources you might find useful:

- [Official Documentation - Object Detection API with TensorFlow 2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md)
- [TF2 Object Detection API - Finetune pretrained model on custom data](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb)